# Code optimization (Tampermonkey)

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I'm using the following code to hide the unwanted divs on your website (while browsing). Unfortunately, there is already so much of that page pretty much overwhelms my computer. Is it possible to optimize it somehow? For example: do not repeat on each line of the whole code?

```
$("div[data-title='Element1']").hide()
$("div[data-title='Element2']").hide()
$("div[data-title='Element3']").hide()
```

Comment: Why not use classes for elements?

Comment: What are you looking for? all elements where `data-title` starts with 'Element?'

Comment: "Element" is just an example. In fact divs have different names. Unfortunately I can't edit the page, I can only make changes in the script Tampermonkey. The code itself works very well, but a large number of these entries slows down my computer. I wonder if this could not be saved in this format: $("div[data-title='Element1, Element2, Element3']").hide()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("div[data-title]:regex(data-title, (Element1|Element2|Element3)$)")
```

You can use a regex to search the data-title attribute for strings.

Comment: Please explain what you are doing and why it solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
var $divs = $("div[data-title]");
$divs.filter("[data-title=Element1],[data-title=Element2],[data-title=Element3]").remove();
```

not much left to optimize after this... maybe lookk into optimizing the rest of your site...